# postgres: could not find the database system

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x, homebrew

If I try to run the `postgres` command, I get:

```
2020-12-29 00:14:53.213 GMT [34374] LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postgresql.auto.conf"
postgres: could not find the database system
Expected to find it in the directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data",
but could not open file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/global/pg_control": No such file or directory
```

**How can I find out what config file is telling postgres to look at /usr/local/pgsql/data?**

In my case, postgres was installed on OSX via Homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know what specific *config file* is pointing to that location, it can be specified when you run the [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-initdb.html) command, which it's sounding like you may not have run yet, given the error you're seeing.

If you just installed a new/upgrade postgres instance, you'll probably want to use a new data directory from whatever your old instance was using (i.e. you can just run the `initdb` command with no additional params, and it will use the default `/usr/local/pgsql/data` location which, apparently, is not yet in use for your machine), then you can export/import the old data if you still need it.